# Get App Users information from google Play Store

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

How can I get information of users which **Installed/Uninstall** my application? Is there any API provided by Google Play Store and App Store?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get only the number of persons who installed your app and uninstalled your app but you can not get the specific user info who have installed or uninstalled your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official api but you can check those unofficial:

[here](https://rapidapi.com/danielamitay/api/app-stores?utm_campaign=api-google-play-store&utm_medium=link&utm_source=quora)

[here](https://rapidapi.com/sphirelabs/api/google-playstore-downloader-and-scrapper?utm_campaign=api-google-play-store&utm_medium=link&utm_source=quora)